# How to stop a tuning_run task in keras/tensorflow/tfrun in R?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I was running this really time-consuming tuning_run() function in R using keras and the package tfruns. It's a neural network with 6 layers with 200 neurons each. I wanted to stop the training tun midway. I can't find the usual red button that appears on the upper right corner of the console which appears when R is doing a task. Is force quitting R the only way?